# Converting string to multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode, substr

I have this as a string input.

```
$str = '[2]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae. [3]Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit. [3]Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor. [3]Donec eget accumsan velit. [4]Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque. [4]Tempo. [2]Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat. [2]Donec eget accumsan velit.';
```

And I'm trying to get to this...

```
array (
[0] => array ( //First [2] and everything below
    [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae.
    [1] => array ( //[3]s that belong to first [2]
        [0] => Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit. //First [3]
        [1] => Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor. //Second [3]
        [2] => array ( //Third [3] and everything below
            [0] => Donec eget accumsan velit.
            [1] => array (
                [0] => Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque.
                [1] => Tempo.
                )
            )
        )
[1] => Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat. //Second [2]
[2] => Donec eget accumsan velit. //Third [2]
```

)

I've tried everything I knew and could find @php.net and everywhere else, but I've spent about six hours on this and I'm still stuck. I've tried explode, preg_replace, array_walk_recursive (along with explode), going from the biggest hierarchy to smaller (best results so far) and the other way around, but nothing. How can I convert a string to a multidimensional array in PHP, setting the hierarchy by tags in the string?

Many thanks!

Comment: You'll need to do this recursively: explode on `[2]` initially, then _walk_ the resultant array splitting on `[3]`, walking the resultant array splitting on `[4]` etc until you get an empty at any level before moving on to the next

Comment: Hey, Mark, thanks for the quick answer!
Everytime I've tried explode, I ended up having the first `[3]`s in the same array level as the parent `[2]`. Only the `[3]` that had `[4]` under it was transfered (later on, by another explode) to a lower level, resulting in the same problem, just a lower deeper in the array.

Comment: I did get a notification of an answer of yours, Mark, but it seems it's now gone. Did anything go wrong @StackOverflow?

Comment: The problem is that the level 2 doesn't follow the same logic as subsequent levels in your subarrays, so it needs an extra check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
$str = '<your_string>';

function stringToArray($str, $delimiter = 2, $isFirst = false) {
    $delimiterStr = "[{$delimiter}]";
    $outArr = array();
    if (strpos($str,$delimiterStr)!==false) {
        $outArr = explode($delimiterStr, $str);         
        $isFirstElement = true;
        $tempArr = array();
        $key = 0;
        foreach ($outArr AS $v) {

            if (!empty($v))
            {
                if ($isFirstElement) {
                    $tempArr[$key] = stringToArray($v, $delimiter+1);
                    $key++;
                } else {
                    $tempArr[$key][] = stringToArray($v, $delimiter+1);
                }                                                       
            }
            $isFirstElement = false;                                
        }
        $outArr = $tempArr;     
    }
    if (!$outArr) {return trim($str);} else {return $outArr;}
}

$elements = stringToArray($str);
print_r($elements[0]);
```

will return

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae.
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit.
                [1] => Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor.
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Donec eget accumsan velit.
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque.
                                [1] => Tempo.
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat.
[2] => Donec eget accumsan velit.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '[2]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae. [3]Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit. [3]Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor. [3]Donec eget accumsan velit. [4]Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque. [4]Tempo. [2]Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat. [2]Donec eget accumsan velit.';

$counter = 2;
function splitLevel($str, $counter) {
    if (strpos($str, '['.$counter.']') === false) {
        return $str;
    }
    $split = array_values(
        array_filter(
            explode('['.$counter.']', $str)
        )
    );

    array_walk(
        $split,
        function(&$value) use ($counter) {
            $value = splitLevel($value, ++$counter);
        }
    );

    if (($counter > 2) && (count($split) > 1)) {
        $first = array_shift($split);
        $split = array($first, $split);
    }
    return $split;
}
$array = splitLevel($str, $counter);

var_dump($array);
```

gives

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(117) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae. "
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(32) "Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit. "
      [1]=>
      string(179) "Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor. "
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(27) "Donec eget accumsan velit. "
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(306) "Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque. "
          [1]=>
          string(7) "Tempo. "
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  string(52) "Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat. "
  [2]=>
  string(26) "Donec eget accumsan velit."
}
```

So just add a bit of extra logic to trim trailing spaces, and you should be good

Comment: That's perfect, Mark! Thank you so much. It runs like a charm on my homeserver (PHP5.4.37). Now I've just found out that my public server runs PHP5.2.42, so I can't run anonymous functions. How can I call array_walk and pass the parameters correctly to a named function?

Comment: You really should be upgrading your public server, PHP 5.2 was end of life  back in 2011, and even PHP 5.3 is 5 months past end of life

Comment: Note that the answer given by @axiac is almost identical to my own in the way it works, and he does show how to avoid the closure for earlier versions of PHP

Comment: I'll try to convince the admins to do so. Thanks for the answer and comments! Despite the minor change, it led me to the right path to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

```
// The string to parse
$str = '[2]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vulputate cursus nulla, at rhoncus ante egestas vitae. [3]Cras euismod aliquet hendrerit. [3]Integer tortor lorem, suscipit a ante id, faucibus iaculis dolor. Sed aliquet, erat sit amet porta efficitur, eros lorem hendrerit purus, eget pellentesque lacus sapien ut dolor. [3]Donec eget accumsan velit. [4]Vestibulum consectetur enim in nunc fermentum lacinia. Maecenas fermentum rutrum sodales. Quisque vulputate, dolor tempus luctus cursus, massa urna ultrices odio, non dictum sem nulla ac mi. Quisque egestas tellus velit, non elementum lorem consequat id. Proin bibendum feugiat mollis. Sed vel odio neque. [4]Tempo. [2]Phasellus ut mauris purus. Quisque vel tortor erat. [2]Donec eget accumsan velit.';

// Parse the string, start with level 2
$array = analyze($str, 2);

// Ignore the fragment before the first '[2]' (it's empty)
array_shift($array);
// Display the list of fragments marked with '[2]` and their offspring
print_r(current($array));


/**
 * Analyze the string $string, search for sections labeled with '[N]'
 * (N = $level).
 * Return an array with two elements: the text before the first '[N]'
 * marker and an array of the fragments that start with '[N]' marker.
 * Each fragment is parsed using the same function.
 *
 * Return the input string ($string) if it does not contain the marker.
 */
function analyze($string, $level)
{
    // The marker
    $marker = '['.$level.']';

    // If the marker does not exist in the string then this is a leaf
    if (strpos($string, $marker) === FALSE) {
        // Return the input string
        return $string;
    }

    // Split by section marker
    $pieces = explode($marker, $string);

    // Extract the first fragment; it is returned as is
    $first = array_shift($pieces);

    // Analyze the pieces, search for the next level
    return array(
        $first,           // First fragment as is
        array_map(        // Parse the rest using the same function (one level deeper)
            function ($piece) use ($level) {
                return analyze($piece, $level + 1);
            },
            $pieces
        ),
    );
}
```

In order to use it on PHP versions before 5.3 (when anonymous functions were introduced), replace the last block of code (starting with `return array(`) with:

```
// Analyze the pieces, search for the next level
$rest = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    $rest[] = analyze($piece, $level + 1);
}
return array($first, $rest);
```